# How to display JSX elements in react-i18next Trans component?

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I am trying to use the react-i18next Trans component to display a JSX element such as a button, but when the text contains a <0></0> placeholder, the element is wrapped inside the placeholder and not displayed. Is there a way to display the element inside the placeholder? This issue occurs not only with buttons but also with other JSX elements such as icons or images.

```
  // this will not show 
   <Trans defaults={"please <0></0>, then."}>
          <button>
            <span>{"a custom link like username"}</span>
          </button>
   </Trans>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFh7s.png)

```
// this will show, but I do not want to add a </span> after this
 <Trans defaults={"please <0></0>, then."}>
          <button>
            <span>{"a custom link like username"}</span>
            <span />
          </button>
 </Trans>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJnOa.png)
Is there other way to add a jsx element at the place where <0></0> is?

I try to add a , it works,but I do not think it is a good solution.
can I just use this to show the button？：

```
 <Trans defaults={" please <0></0>, then."}>
          <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
            <span>{'a custom link like username'}</span>
          </a>
   </Trans>
```